Getting source file info with prolog_load_context sets script=false in swi-prolog 8.2.4
I have this trivial Prolog program:
% bug_repro.pro 
am_i_a_script(Bool) :- prolog_load_context(script, Bool).

If I understand the docs correctly:
https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=prolog_load_context/2
Bool should unify with true, since the call to prolog_load_context is inside a file.
However when I load it in the swipl interpreter and query the predicate, it says it's not a script:
?- version.
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.2.4)
[...]
true.

?- ['bug_repro.pro'].
true.

?- am_i_a_script(Result).
Result = false.

I get the same result when running the query from the command line, both with the -s and -l options:
$ swipl -q -t halt -s bug_repro.pro -g 'am_i_a_script(Result), write(Result), nl'
false
$ swipl -q -t halt -l bug_repro.pro -g 'am_i_a_script(Result), write(Result), nl'
false

Also, not getting the directory key (which is what I'm really interested in).
Is this a bug or I'm missing something?
(I'm running this on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye).)
Edit:
As suggested by @brebs, here are all the key/value pairs I get from prolog_load_context:
$ cat context.pro 

context :-
  prolog_load_context(Key, Val), write(Key), write(':'), write(Val), nl, false.

$ swipl -q -s context.pro 
?- context.
module:user
dialect:swi
script:false
variable_names:[]
term:[]
false.

?- source_file(context, File).
File = '/home/<edited>/context.pro'.

Note that source_file correctly returns the absolute path of the file where the context predicate lives.
(However if the predicate is loaded indirectly from a module, source_file fails--perhaps a related issue.)

To see what works, just run: prolog_load_context(Key, Val).

Thanks @brebs, see edit in the post for the output.

I'd recommend to ask this at https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/

OK, so this post has the answer to this question:
https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/why-is-prolog-load-context-with-user-file-search-path-done-this-way/5543/1
Basically, prolog_load_context/2 is supposed to be called as a directive (not as a regular predicate), since the actual context data is available only at compile time.
In other words, this works:
:- prolog_load_context(directory, Dir),
   asserta(user:file_search_path(myapp, Dir)).

But this doesn't:
user:file_search_path(myapp, Dir) :-
   prolog_load_context(directory, Dir).

